# Javascript code giving if condition error in console

Tags: javascript, php

```
<?php
if($_GET['st'] !=''){
$st= $_GET['st'];
?>
    <script>
    var st = <?php echo  $st; ?>
    if(st !=''){
        console.log('got function here');
    }
    </script> 
<?php }?>
```

i want to show if the $st is not equal to empty then do something else do something else but its giving error

> pro.php?st=foo:13 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if.

Comment: Instead of `st = <?php echo  $st; ?>` use `st = "<?php echo  $st; ?>";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
<?php
  if($_GET['st'] !=''){
  $st= $_GET['st'];
?>
<script>
  var st = "<?php echo  $st; ?>"; // assign var st properly with ("st";)
  if(st !=''){
  console.log('got function here');
  }    
</script> 
<?php 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `st = <?php echo $st; ?>` use `st = "<?php echo $st; ?>";`, You need to close the statement of PHP and javascript.

```
<?php
if($_GET['st'] !=''){
$st= $_GET['st'];
?>
    <script>
    var st = "<?php echo  $st; ?>";
    if(st !=''){
        console.log('got function here');
    }
    </script> 
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store `st` inside the quotes, something like that:

```
var st = '<?=$st?>';
```

But before that, you also need to use `isset()` for checking either `$_GET['st']` set or not along with `!empty()` condition.

**Example:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['st']) && !empty($_GET['st'])){
  $st = $_GET['st'];
?>
    <script>
    var st = '<?=$st?>';
    if(st != ''){
      console.log('got function here');
    }
    </script> 
<?php 
}
?>
```

Note that, you have already check the empty value in `PHP`, don't know why are you using it again in `javascript`.